# Variable accessible to all instances of a class

Tags: c++, class

Let's say I have a lookup table which I'd like to make accessible to all instances of `Foo`. Should I make the table `private static`? If not, what should I do?

Basically I want a way to save just one copy of the table (so it doesn't consume extra memory for each instance of `Foo`) and have it available privately to all instances of `Foo`.

Comment: Yes, `private static` is perfect. It's private, and it isn't dependent on any particular instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like private static to me.